# Looking for examples of Domain Events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, domain-driven-design, domain-events

Does any one know where to find example code for an implementation of Domain Events as described by [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/) in [Domain Events – Salvation](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DDDSample.Net [has one](http://dddsamplenet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/48934#777714).

Answer (score 13):

A better implementation of Domain Events, in my opinion, can be found at https://github.com/bsommardahl/BlingBag. There's a sample application and implementation instructions. I like this implementation more because it doesn't use the static class to raise domain events and doesn't couple your domain to your infrastructure. Instead it uses plain ole c# events and initializes them in the services that return your domain entities (like your repository or a fetcher service).

Comment: Yep, thanks for the heads up. I just fixed it. https://github.com/bsommardahl/BlingBag

Comment: It looks cool, but I guess it's abandoned now? Would be good to see a .NET Standard version

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty neat implementation of Udi Dahan, http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/. Recommended by Steve Smith and Julie Lerman in their course [Domain-Driven Design Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/domain-driven-design-fundamentals)